# Inserting/Merging Two Columns Into One - Concat

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, insert

Been able to get my syntax pretty close with many of the posts on this forum (that you for that), but not all the way.

I'm trying to create an Artificial Primary Key/Surrogate Key from combining two columns with the same data type in a table. I've created a 3rd column specifically to hold this combined value.

My Syntax is

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A ( ARTPRIMKEY )
    SELECT (COLUMN1 ||'-'|| COLUMN2) 
    FROM TABLE A;
```

But rather than filling in the new column in the correct sequence, it inserts new rows, all with NULLS effectively doubling the number of rows but not doing what I want it to do.

Should I be looking at doing a merge instead (although I'm not sure where my match condition is)?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a composite key/unique index on column1, column2?  If values for col1, col2 change the new artprimkey value would not change and perhaps you need it to? What's the value of this surrogate key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want `update`:

```
update a
    set artprimkey = (COLUMN1 ||'-'|| COLUMN2) ;
```

In more recent versions of Oracle, you could generate the key as a computed column,so you don't actually have to store the value in the table.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much, appreciate the quick turnaround.